# Highlight questions I already voted to close in the question list

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, question-lists

In the question list, it is easy to recognize questions that are closed or on hold because this status is added to their title. Unfortunately, there is no indication for already having voted to close on questions that are *not yet closed*.

That's a pitty, because I often read questions, decide that I want to vote to close and than realize that I already did that. The problem is, bad questions often don't have very descriptive titles which makes it difficult to remember them.

I suppose that this is not so much of a problem in very frequented tags where questions get closed quickly (?) and most users see each question only once. However, in low-traffic tags closing sometimes takes long and it is easy to stumble over the same question many times.

Therefore **I propose that users that already voted to close a question see some kind of indicator on the respective questions**. This could be similar to the `[closed]` suffix on the title of already closed questions, but with a different wording like `[voted to close]` (or something more succint).

Comment: While it's not as easy as what you propose, you can see a close vote history in your profile `Profile > Votes > closure`

Comment: Even/especially in high traffic tags this is an issue...I fully endorse this feature request.

Comment: @Machavity Sure. It's no problem to find out on which questions I already voted. The goal of my proposal is to regognize these questions when skimming the question list.

Comment: On some tags, the load may be reduced by only highlighting the questions that the user has not yet CV.

Comment: I think that the solution will involve the API and a userscript.

Comment: A search expression "I have a close vote active on this question" would solve this?  Letting you filter out such questions, which I suspect you want to do?

Comment: @Yakk: Do you mean a new search operator like `havevoted:no`? Yes, this would be convenient, but IMHO not as conventient as what I proposed because it doesn't apply when simply clicking on a tag, for example.

Comment: @Braiam You are right, a user script should be a possible solution.