# Indicate within questions that I already voted to close/reopen

Tags: feature-request, status-review, vote-to-close

I vote to close/migrate off-topic questions frequently, and I revisit questions often due to reply to comments, update my ancient answers, etc.

I can't always remember if I previously voted to close a question, and there is no visual cue to indicate that I already voted. As a result I will often click on the close link only to realize that I already voted.

You can see the current situation in the images below.

Before voting:

[image: Before voting]

After voting:

[image: After voting]

**I'd like to see the number of votes or the close link to be displayed differently**, such as in italics or whatever, after I vote so I know that I already voted. Thus, literally saving seconds per day to allow me to more efficiently pile more questions onto the mouldering, omnipresent, and mountainous heap of the off-topic queue.

AdrianHHH in a comment mentions the tooltip when hovering over the close link will indicate that I voted. This is nice, but I'd still like to know if I voted without needing to hover.

I don't consider this to be a duplicate of *[Highlight questions I already voted to close in the question list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316612/highlight-questions-i-already-voted-to-close-in-the-question-list)*, because I would prefer to see the indication within the question itself.

Comment: Hovering the pointer over the "close" or "close(\d+)" should give a tooltip, but with different contents depending on whether you have voted to close that question or not.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thanks. Didn't know about that.

Comment: I was about to post the same request. If the text "close" was changed to match the colour of the up/downvoting arrows it would be helpful.

Comment: I "solved" this by not voting to migrate anymore since such questions almost never get enough votes for the migration to actually occur and it became a waste of time and effort.

Comment: This is also a concern when reopening.

Comment: <https://stackapps.com/q/9286/77981>

Answer (score 19):

I think this is a very good suggestion. I often find myself in the situation where I browse older questions from an earlier time of the day, or the day(s) before. There are many low quality questions and I do not necessarily remember all that I have seen. It is very frustrating to click on 'Close', only to find out that I already had voted previously.

I would suggest to add an asterisk or discrete character to indicate this:

For instance, this would indicate that I did not yet vote:

[image: I did not yet vote to close]

While something like this would immediately tell me that I already did:

[image: I already voted to close]

I know one can hover on the menu to get a tooltip, but this is just too slow.

As a further argument to those that might consider it not worth the change. Imagine if you had no **direct** indication that you up/down-voted a Q/A. How often do you think you would mistakenly click the button again?

Comment: I prefer the asterisk after the vote. For that, it could be implemented by adding the following CSS:`.js-post-menu button[title*="You"] .existing-flag-count:after, .js-post-menu button[title*="you"] .existing-flag-count:after { content:"*)"; }` While I have tested this on MSE, I can't test it on MSO or SO. The selectors could probably be reduced to a single selector `.js-post-menu button[title^="You"] .existing-flag-count:after `, but I went with the longer two selectors due to a lack of testing. Obviously, if you wanted the asterisk in front you could use a `:before { content:"(*"; }`.