# Why doesn't a vote to the delete button show I already voted?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, vote-to-delete

I noticed quite a few times that after I voted to delete a question (or an answer), the button for it shows as *"X more votes are needed to delete this post"* when simply hovering over it.

If I click on it, a popup alert shows *"Vote to delete this post?"*, yet I'd of expected it to inform me that I have already voted, instead of going through the process, only to finally be told that I already voted to delete.

Just like a vote to close that I already voted on, shows an indication that I already voted; the vote to delete button shouldn't show as *"X more votes are needed to delete this post"*, but something like *"You have already voted to delete"*, wouldn't you agree?

As would be the case with if I voted to close a question and retracted my vote, it shows me that I have already voted so I can't go any further.

Sidenote: I looked for a similar question on meta, but I did not find one.

Should this best be left alone and that's how it should remain because it may have been how it was intended to function, or something that should be looked into and added as a feature?

Comment: I'd like the same for Close Votes too...while they are at it :)

Comment: This sounds less like a bug and more like a feature request.  It's not a bug since this is how the behavior has always been, and it (likely) should change.

Comment: @Makoto *Hm..* you could be right. I'll add the tag and leave the one for "bug" in there, just in case it could be one. I am pretty sure the mods will pick up on it and will remove it if it isn't, thanks. Edit: I added the tag.

Comment: @Makoto I removed the "bug" tag and made a slight edit to the question.

Comment: I bet this is for performance reasons, they only check if you already voted to delete when you try to cast a deletion vote, so they don't have to check that for every post you view.

Comment: [this bug was reported at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285065/165773) (supposedly a regression caused by recent update of jQuery)

Comment: @gnat Oh, I see. I am following that question as a matter of fact. I had the "bug" tag in my question originally and was given a comment by another member just above about it not being one, (and I removed it), saying that is how the behavior has always been. Kind of hard to say if it was or not, but thanks for letting me know about that link on MSE.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm starting to wonder if that (about what you said for the Close Votes) isn't also part of a bug, or has always had that behavior, if you go over the (new) comments here.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: it's hard to imagine there'd be a significant performance issue. SO already has to know the current vote counts for every post (potentially several on a single page), as well as whether you up- or down-voted. Likewise any flagged comments. Given the network traffic already involved, it shouldn't require a major increase to show whether one has voted "close" or "delete" on a post.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Except it *is* a large amount of work to retrieve close votes. Some time ago I had an app that would open the 'close vote' window to get some stats on questions. It made a request maybe once every 5 seconds, and was asked to shut down the application as it was causing unnecessary load. It's also the reason there's a time limit preventing you from opening the close dialog in rapid succession.

Comment: @Rob: there's a huge difference between a script that pings the server every 5 seconds, and simply including the data in the initial query when the page is loaded. The issue in the former isn't the amount of data some specific information requires, but rather that the data is being requested _many_ times.

Comment: @PeterDuniho If my script hitting the server every 5 seconds caused big issues, then tens/hundreds of page views per second, which *include* the data I was asking for would be a huge problem.

Comment: @Rob: sorry Rob, your extrapolation simply isn't a valid analysis. You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I really don't think I am, to be honest. It's not apples to oranges, unless you are led to believe that embedding the vote count into a page is less expensive than retrieving it for an API call? The problem lied in *fetching* the vote information. That vote information would be fetched for every single page view. If fetching it every 5 seconds bogs down the server, how do you suppose fetching it every 1/20th of a second would be any better? Where exactly is my comparison invalid here?

Comment: Reminds me of my question, [Indicate within question that I already voted to close](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326967/1109017).

Comment: "Do you want fries with that?" "No." "Do you want ketchup with those fries?" I hope this gets fixed.

Comment: I believe this has been implemented. When you hover over the delete button the text for the tooltip is fetched from the server. The text which is then displayed shows if you are the one that voted. Is this implementation sufficient for what you were desiring?

Comment: @Makyen It seems to have been (somewhat) resolved. I'm just wondering why the popup alert box (not the red one that appears after) still shows up, the first one being *"Vote to delete this post?"* with the "OK/Cancel". In sorts, if I/someone already voted, you'd think that that shouldn't be showing at all.

Comment: I agree, but that sounds like a different bug/RFE.