# Change the "flag" label below flagged posts to better reflect its state

Tags: feature-request, flags

After you flag a post, you still see the same "Flag" link below it, even though it's now also "observe flagging, change flag or retract it". I suggest that the label be changed somewhat, e.g. updated in one or more of these ways:

1. Changing the color to dark red
2. Emboldening
3. Adding "..."
4. "Flag" -> "Flagged"

Comment: Or maybe change it to "Flagged", analogous with the Follow link that changes to "Following" after it is clicked.

Comment: @Marijn: Added that option. But I would also change the formatting, otherwise it suggests that it's flagged and you can no longer do anything about it.

Comment: Maybe make it analogous to how the `Close` action looks like after a close-vote was cast? E.g. `Flag (1)`, but that `(1)` would probably be just be visible to the user that cast the vote.

Comment: Related: [Indicate within questions that I already voted to close/reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326967/indicate-within-questions-that-i-already-voted-to-close-reopen) and [Why doesn't a vote to the delete button show I already voted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335794/why-doesnt-a-vote-to-the-delete-button-show-i-already-voted)

Comment: @Lino: If the number of flags mattered, that would make more sense...